# Logback MDC on Netty or any other non-blocking IO server

Tags: spring-boot, netty, logback, mdc, distributed-tracing

Logback MDC (Mapped Diagnostic Context) is leveraging threadLocal (As far as I know) so that it will be accessible on all the log statements executed by the same thread.

My question is, will logback MDC work in the non blocking IO server-side runtime like Netty or Undertow as it used to work in for example, tomcat?
If yes, how is it working as Netty/Undertow is not following one-thread-per-request unlike tomcat.

I am trying to put a traceID in MDC, so that I can trace all my log from a one transaction trail across multiple microservices/pipeline-listeners in a centralized logging system like Splunk/ELK

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not terribly familiar with using netty directly, but I do know that it is possible to use logback MDC with asynchronous code. It isn't easy though.

Basically you need to somehow tie the traceId to the request/connection, and each time you start processing for that connection, set the traceId in the MDC for the current thread.

If you are using a thread pool, you can do this with a custom Executor that gets the current state (ex. traceId) from the current thread local storage, and creates a wrapped Runnable or Callable that sets thread local storage to the previously retrieved value before running. That wrapped runnable is then forwarded to a delegate Executor.

You can see how this is done here: https://github.com/lucidsoftware/java-thread-context/blob/master/thread-context/src/main/java/com/github/threadcontext/PropagatingExecutorService.java

In fact, depending on your needs, you may be able to use that java-thread-context project.

Comment: This is called propagating thread pool and this is  how we implemented mdc available on all threads from the pool.

Answer (score 1):

As you have mentioned, the MDC implementation is based on the `ThreadLocal`, so it's not really applicable to the Reactor.

What I would suggest in case of Reactor (I assume you are using it by the tags) is:

1. Using the `Context` [(docs here)](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/util/context/Context.html?is-external=true) available in `Mono` and `Flux` in order to store the `traceId` to be available during the execution.
2. If you're using Spring-Webflux and you want to generate the `tradeId` and add it to the `Context` in one place, then you can use the `WebFilter` [(docs here)](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web-reactive.html#webflux-web-handler-api) to do that.
3. Then you can retrieve the data from the context using some custom
   helper methods, like in [example by Nicolas Portman](https://ndportmann.com/logging-with-context-in-spring-webflux/), or create your own custom logging format, where you utilize the data from the `Context`.